Accessing a shared map in go concurrently
I'm new at concurrency and I'm facing the following problem.
I have an external for loop, for getting rows from the database. I want in every single loop to fill the vertexDistribution map
for year := estart; year <= eend; year++ {
        vertexDistribution[year] += degree
}

But when the id I get from the database is not the same as the previous one, I want the go routine to fill the degreeDistribution map (which gets its data from vertexDistribution map).
timeStart := time.Now()
for rows.Next() {

    err = rows.Scan(&sourceid, &degree, &estart, &eend)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error scanning the rows of degree distribution: ", err)
    }

    if prevsourceid != sourceid && prevsourceid != "" {
        mutex.Lock()
        temp := vertexDistribution
        mutex.Unlock()

        vertexDistribution = make(map[int]int) // clear the map

        go func(temp map[int]int) {
            mutex.Lock()
            defer mutex.Unlock()
            for k, v := range temp {
                if _, ok := degreeDistribution[k]; !ok {
                    degreeDistribution[k] = make(map[int]int)
                }
                degreeDistribution[k][v]++
            }
        }(temp)
    }

    for year := estart; year <= eend; year++ {
        vertexDistribution[year] += degree
    }

    prevsourceid = sourceid
}

mutex.Lock()
defer mutex.Unlock()
for k, v := range vertexDistribution { // covering the last vertexDistribution data
    if _, ok := degreeDistribution[k]; !ok {
        degreeDistribution[k] = make(map[int]int)
    }
    degreeDistribution[k][v]++
}

elapsedTime := time.Since(timeStart)
fmt.Println(elapsedTime.Seconds(), "seconds elapsed getting the degree distribution")

Apparently I have get the concept wrong, sometimes the output is right, sometimes is wrong and sometimes I get fatal error: concurrent map iteration and map write
I ran go run -race main.go and got
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c000192000 by main goroutine:
  reflect.maplen()
      /usr/local/go/src/runtime/map.go:1406 +0x0
  reflect.Value.lenNonSlice()
      /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:1785 +0x1e9
  reflect.Value.Len()
      /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:1774 +0x137
  internal/fmtsort.Sort()
      /usr/local/go/src/internal/fmtsort/sort.go:58 +0x121
  fmt.(*pp).printValue()
      /usr/local/go/src/fmt/print.go:816 +0x1144
  fmt.(*pp).printValue()
      /usr/local/go/src/fmt/print.go:827 +0x2c8f
  fmt.(*pp).printArg()
      /usr/local/go/src/fmt/print.go:759 +0xb84
  fmt.(*pp).doPrintln()
      /usr/local/go/src/fmt/print.go:1221 +0x4b
  fmt.Fprintln()
      /usr/local/go/src/fmt/print.go:304 +0x52
  fmt.Println()
      /usr/local/go/src/fmt/print.go:314 +0x247
  main.main()
      /home/xaris/VScode/HiNode-CockroachDB/main.go:21 +0x1e6

Previous write at 0x00c000192000 by goroutine 22575:
  runtime.mapassign_fast64()
      /usr/local/go/src/runtime/map_fast64.go:93 +0x0
  hinode/models.MultiTable.GetDegreeDistributionConcurrently.func1()
      /home/xaris/VScode/HiNode-CockroachDB/models/multiTable.go:352 +0x184
  hinode/models.MultiTable.GetDegreeDistributionConcurrently.gowrap1()
      /home/xaris/VScode/HiNode-CockroachDB/models/multiTable.go:354 +0x41

Goroutine 22575 (finished) created at:
  hinode/models.MultiTable.GetDegreeDistributionConcurrently()
      /home/xaris/VScode/HiNode-CockroachDB/models/multiTable.go:345 +0x8b6
  main.main()
      /home/xaris/VScode/HiNode-CockroachDB/main.go:19 +0x1d6
==================
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c0000eaca8 by main goroutine:
  reflect.typedmemmove()
      /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mbarrier.go:203 +0x0
  reflect.copyVal()
      /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:2064 +0x5b
  reflect.(*MapIter).Value()
      /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:1961 +0x124
  internal/fmtsort.Sort()
      /usr/local/go/src/internal/fmtsort/sort.go:64 +0x3b6
  fmt.(*pp).printValue()
      /usr/local/go/src/fmt/print.go:816 +0x1144
  fmt.(*pp).printValue()
      /usr/local/go/src/fmt/print.go:827 +0x2c8f
  fmt.(*pp).printArg()
      /usr/local/go/src/fmt/print.go:759 +0xb84
  fmt.(*pp).doPrintln()
      /usr/local/go/src/fmt/print.go:1221 +0x4b
  fmt.Fprintln()
      /usr/local/go/src/fmt/print.go:304 +0x52
  fmt.Println()
      /usr/local/go/src/fmt/print.go:314 +0x247
  main.main()
      /home/xaris/VScode/HiNode-CockroachDB/main.go:21 +0x1e6

Previous write at 0x00c0000eaca8 by goroutine 22577:
  hinode/models.MultiTable.GetDegreeDistributionConcurrently.func1()
      /home/xaris/VScode/HiNode-CockroachDB/models/multiTable.go:352 +0x193
  hinode/models.MultiTable.GetDegreeDistributionConcurrently.gowrap1()
      /home/xaris/VScode/HiNode-CockroachDB/models/multiTable.go:354 +0x41

Goroutine 22577 (finished) created at:
  hinode/models.MultiTable.GetDegreeDistributionConcurrently()
      /home/xaris/VScode/HiNode-CockroachDB/models/multiTable.go:345 +0x8b6
  main.main()
      /home/xaris/VScode/HiNode-CockroachDB/main.go:19 +0x1d6
==================


Run the code with the race detector, and it will show you the exact locations of the conflicting map access.

Theres probably no reason to be using concurrency here anyway. There is little to be gained by filling the maps with a bunch of goroutines.

Sorry I was wrong, I was comparing it with a wrong function. You are right, as a matter of fact its not faster at all

The "concurrent map iteration and map write" typically means you're iterating over a map and then attempting to add new keys to the same map within that for-loop. I don't see where this is happening in your code example but the panic should have given you a line number to investigate.
More generally, if you're going to have multiple routines reading/writing to the same maps I would suggest defining safe methods to interact with those data objects and then only using those methods. For example:
type Distribution struct {
    store map[int]int
    mu sync.Mutex
}

func (d *Distribution) Insert(k, v int) {
    d.mu.Lock()
    d.store[k] = v
    d.mu.Unlock()
}

... additional methods for Distribution operations ...

This will force you to think through which operations are safe concurrently and which require mutual exclusion, then implement that once before getting to your business logic.
Also, if you're just using these for counters, take a look at atomic counters in the sync package. They may fit some parts of your use case.

yes you are right, the initial thought was to use vertexDistribution map instead of temp map, but then there would be no reason for concurrency.
